# sql query returns incorrect result

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database that stores quotation documents with some products that are clearly defining the price of each product in them, and a table for contracts storing contract details as well as customer code and quotation code to which it belongs. I have the following query to see how much is the total price of the quotation to write it in the invoice:

```
select
   sum(sqproducts.price * sqproducts.quantity) as 'total-price',
   squotations.currency as 'currency'
from
  sqproducts,
  ccontracts,
  squotations
where 
  sqproducts.contracted=1
  AND squotations.code=sqproducts.quotation_code
  AND sqproducts.quotation_code=ccontracts.squotation_code
  AND sqproducts.quotation_code='QUOT/2012/1'
group by
  currency
```

[image: the following is the sqproducts table(details about the products named in quotation)]

[image: But I get this result which is not correct (it must result 1500 USD)]

Comment: Why dont you group by product?

Comment: that leads to an undesired answer either. It multiplies the wrong way

Comment: Isn't this clear enough? or what??

Comment: Why don't you create a schema in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I have a squotations table holding code as it's PK and a sqproducts table with an auto-incremented integer PK as well as squotations code as FK. the squotations PK is also a FK in ccontracts table. I thought this might help us!

Comment: how can that help me? would you explain please!

Comment: Please show the exact rows returned from your above listing, plz include the currency column too

Comment: well the result of the query is exactly that smaller picture up there in the post. do u mean that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13273/discussion-between-sashi-kant-and-reza-saberi)

Answer (score 0):

Its a blind hit , Try this one:

```
select
   sum(sqproducts.price * sqproducts.quantity) as 'total-price',
   squotations.currency as 'currency'
from
  sqproducts 
inner join squotations on (squotations.code=sqproducts.quotation_code)
inner join ccontracts on (sqproducts.quotation_code=ccontracts.squotation_code)

where 
  sqproducts.contracted=1
  AND sqproducts.quotation_code='QUOT/2012/1'
group by
  squotations.currency
```

Comment: returning same result as my own query!